# $.getJSON is not calling call back function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

call back in not being called.

```
function GetTrainingResults(id,callback){
    $.getJSON("/dashboard/GetTrainingResults/", {'id':id}, callback);
}
GetTrainingResults('id',function(result){
    alert(result);
});
```

and code behind is

```
 public ActionResult GetTrainingResults(int id)
    {
        string test = "You are there.";
        return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Or suggest and another way. Task in to call controller method and wait for method response in javascript.

Thanks

Comment: current code successfully fire the code behing but it did not call the call back function.

Comment: Use the full .ajax function to see if its hitting error rather than success. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `jQuery.ajax`, you'll at least be able to see the error being returned by the server:

```
function getTrainingResults(id, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/dashboard/GetTrainingResults/",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            callback(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: success and error callbacks are deprecated as of jQUery 1.8 and removed on 2.0. Use the promises "done" or "fail" instead. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Ooops, I still need to investigate 2.0. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

`id` in your Action method takes an `int`, yet you're passing it a `string` of `'id'` in your JS. Either change your JS or you action method so that the types match.

Comment: when i change it id from 'id' in JS it says id is undefined.

Comment: @SirajHussain You should change it to a number, something like `GetTrainingResults(1, function(result){`

Answer (score 0):

Check that your request is returning successfully, the ajax shorthand functions only call the callback if the request is successful (ie status code 200 and of the right data type, ie json). Try the full .ajax jquery function and see whats going on under the hood.

.getJSON() is equivient too

```
$.ajax({
 dataType: "json",
 url: url,
 data: data,
 success: success
});
```

so it might be hitting error: due to the data type.

Source http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/